# discrete math: n pennies among k children with each child having atleast 2 pennies

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This problem is posed in Lovasz's Discrete math book chapter 3 and I understand the **correct** answer which is $$ \binom{n-k-1}{k-1} $$

However, why is my approach not right ? Here it goes.
We have n pennies. We group them into 2 each  and hence have 
$$
\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor
$$
units. Lets call them U. 
Now we have to distribute U units among k-1 children which will lead to

$$ \binom{\lfloor{\frac{n-2}{2}}\rfloor-2}{k-1} $$
ways. I subtracted 2 because 2 pennies will goto the first child.

Comment: Is my answer to a different question which is num ways for each child to get an even number of pennies ? Hence it is incorrect for the Lovasz's textbook question.

Comment: Your approach would never give the first child more than $2$ pennies.  Nor would it give two different children an odd number of pennies each.  And it is unclear what it counting anyway: what does it mean when $n=4$ and $k=2$? Or $n=10$ and $k=2$?

Comment: I think your approach is counting the number of ways of distributing U units among k children, with each unit having 2 pennies. But it doesn't count the number of distributions where the kids get odd number of coins.
Also, when n is odd, you seem to be ignoring the coin that is left over.
Hope this helps.

And coming to the actual expression, I think you are counting the number of ways of "choosing k Units from the U units" or something similar - it is not distributing the U units among k children.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have n pennies, and you want to distribute them among k children, with each child having at least 2 pennies. You can go as follow:

Distribute 2 pennies to k child.

Since the pennies are identical, the order you distribute the pennies to the children does not matter.

Then there is only one way to do that.

Now you left with n-2K pennies.

And the number of distributing the remaining pennies is:

$(n-2k)+k-1 \choose k-1 $ = $ n-k-1 \choose k-1$.
[By the previous theorem in the textbook].

So the total number is:

$ (1) $ $ n-k-1 \choose k-1$ = $ n-k-1 \choose k-1$.

Answer (score -1):

You can see that your answer is wrong when different $n$ give the same answer.

What you should do is give to each child $2$ pennies.

You are left with $n-2k$ pennies and you want to give them to $k$ children.

Can you take it from here?

Recall that the number of ways to give $m$ pennies to $r$ children is
$$\binom{m+r-1}{r-1}.$$